# input type="text" not resizing

Tags: html, css, input

On the page http://qa.salemgolfclub.org/Directions, there is a section at the bottom (next the the "Directions" button) that has an `input` where you can put an address and use Google Maps for driving directions.

One thing that I can't figure out is no matter what I enter for the `size` property on the textbox, it always shows up as the same size.

As you can see, I have it set to:

```html
 <input type="text" size="300" id="fromAddress" name="from" value="" />
```

but it clearly doesn't look this long, though it definitely looks like there is real estate left on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width of the field is set by CSS. More specifically in line 319 of your Site.css, to 200 pixels. Stylesheets always higher priority than markup.

Comment: inline styles have higher precedence and priority than stylesheets

Comment: +1 for Russ here's more http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Comment: Good catch. Wasn't thinking about that when I replied. Personally I would advise against using either size="XXX" or style="width: YYY", as referencing an external CSS file provides a much cleaner markup and better separation of content from presentation.

Answer (score 2):

Change the width in the style

```
style="width: 100px"
```

It would be better to apply a css class for this particular text field and then apply the style in that class. Do avoid inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

if you change it to

```
style= "width: 300px;"
```

then it is resized

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you have the `width: 200px;` on `input[type=text]`.

Changing this value will allow you to change the width of the box.

Answer (score 0):

you’ll probably assign the width with CSS for your id #fromAddress, and CSS’ width has higher priority than the attribute size

Answer (score 0):

using stylizer, the property that control the size of your box is "INPUT[type="text"]".
So you need to change it

It's in your site.Css file